# running classic asp alongside .net

Tags: .net, iis, asp-classic

I work on a site built in .net that accesses classic asp pages (on the same server) via iframes.

To pass session we use an iframe to thew classic asp page with querystring values, and this sets the QS values into classic asp session.

One of our customers has sent a http archive which confirms the iframe can sometimes take up to 6 minutes to completely load. Here is the content of that iframe

```
<%
    session("USERID") = Request.QueryString("s")
    session("CUSTOMERGUID") = "{" & UCase(Request.Querystring("t")) & "}"
%>
```

Can anyone think of a reason why this would take 6 minutes to load?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that possible reason -- your web server too busy (too many connection/active users, not enought RAM or CPU too busy).

Also, in your ASP (classic ASP) web site -- anything special inside Global.asa ? Are you using it?

Comment: Thanks, no global.asa is used, but worth an upvote as I should have mentioned that! Would it be possible for the .net part of the site to run fine whilst traffic causes the classic asp portion to be slow?

Comment: If ASP and ASP.NET web sites running as one application -- under one application pool, then asnwer NO. You could limit bandwidth traffic and CPU usage for the same application/application pool, but since ASP.NET works fine, ASP web site also should works fine.

How about this: can you 
1) make clone of web site
2) stop ASP.NET part of web site
3) make some speed test of ASP web site

Comment: Ill give it a go - im looking at something else for now but will post details when i get a chance. Thanks zam